# Can I play 4k video on my TV through my MacBook using a Thunderbolt/HDMI cable?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport, 4k

A silly question perhaps, but nonetheless...
I own an early 2015, 13-inch MacBook Air, and I recently purchased a 4k 43' TCL TV with HDMI 2.0 ports.

I'm thinking about purchasing a Thunderbolt/MiniDisplay to HDMI cable that supports 4k@60Hz. Is this a worthwhile investment, or will my MacBook's capabilities hinder the ability to play 4k videos on the TV through my MacBook?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the correct mini-DP to HDMI cable will work and your MacBook is not limiting this.

Have a look at the tech specs from your [MacBook Air](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP714?locale=en_US) or read this article on [macrumors](https://www.macrumors.com/2015/03/25/2015-macbook-air-4k-display-60hz/).